# Transfer funds to connected stripe account located in different regions

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using stripe in my project in which the platform account is located in UK and the connected (custom) accounts are located in different countries. I want to send money to different accounts based on some rating. I want to do this in the python. Now the problem is whenever i try to transfer funds in the same region, it works fine but when i try to send funds to accounts located outside I get this error

> Funds can't be sent to accounts located in AU because it's restricted outside of your platform's region

I am trying seperate charges and transfer because i want to send multiple accounts some money. Is there any way to do it? I also tried contacting with stripe customer support but they were not much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripe Docs on [Separate Charges & Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers) point out that is generally is not possible

> In most scenarios, your platform and any connected account must be in the same region. Attempting to transfer funds across a disallowed border returns an error.

There is a separate doc that mentions [cross-border transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#transfers-cross-border) but you will likely need to contact [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true) to determine whether you qualify and how to go about this.

Comment: Is there any other way to send money to stripe connected accounts based in different countries?

Comment: Not currently that I know of.  International banking regulations make it tricky so your best option is to talk to Support.